# More efficient way to get measurements from different items in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm currently getting a bunch of accuracy measurements for 80k different items which I need to calculate the measurements independently but currently is taking too long, so want to determine a faster way to do it.

Here's my code in R with it's comments:

work_file: Contains 4 varables: item_id, Dates, demand and forecast

my code:

```
output<-0

uniques<- unique(work_file$item_id)
for( i in uniques){

#filter every unique item
temporal<- work_file %>% filter(item_id==i)

#Calculate the accuracy measure for each item
x<-temporal$demand
x1<-temporal$forecast
item_error<- c(i, accuracy(x1,x)
output<-rbind(output, item_error)}
```

For 80k~unique items is taking hours,

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try with groupby operation i.e. `library(data.table)setDT(work_file)[, .(acc = accuracy(forecast, demand)), item_id]`

Comment: Where's the code for `accuracy`?

Answer (score 1):

R is a vectorized language, as such one can avoid the use of the loop.  Also the binding within a loop is especially slow since the output data structure is constantly being deleted and recreated with each iteration.

Provided the "accuracy()" function can accept a vector input this should work: Without sample data to test, there is always some doubt.

```
answer<- work_file %>% 
      group_by(item_id) %>% 
      summarize(accuracy(forecast, demand))
```

Here the dplyr's group_by function will collect the different item_ids and the pass those vectors to summarize the accuracy function.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, is there any way to check how much data is there left to process? for example 500 out of 80k

Comment: Sorry but no.   This one line of code is all complied and it should run rather quickly.  If it is still running slow, it maybe the code for the "accuracy" function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `data.table` methods which would be efficient

```
library(data.table)
setDT(work_file)[, .(acc = accuracy(forecast, demand)), item_id]
```